# Microsoft Teams - Can't Connect To The Internet - Request Timeout After Second Start

Tags: microsoft-teams

After a clean install, I can start Teams, login and use it normally for the *first run* only. But when I close the application and try to restart it later, there is a delay of around 55 seconds, which ends with a request timeout. 
[image: Request time out error]

I tried to delete the files in the Teams folder and found that the error wouldn't happen the following file was deleted:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Teams\settings.json
```

However, every time Teams is started, the file is created or overwritten again.

The next step was to find the exact setting within the settings.json file.
After I change the *enableProcessIntegrityLevel* property-value from *true* to *false* and save the file, Teams starts once, without the timeout error:

```
"enableProcessIntegrityLevel":false
```

What does this value exactly do and how can I fix the problem?

Teams version 1.0 did not have this issue, but I updated to a newer version and cannot downgrade to the version that worked for me.

**Some Details:**

Teams version: `1.2.00.8864 x64 (last, from 30.03.2019)`

Tried on:

- Windows Server 2016 x64 1607 Build (14393.1884)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 7601 Build SP1
- Windows 7 x64 / Windows 10 x64

Error message:

```
Oh no ... we can't connect to the internet. Check your connection
Error code - Request timeout
Failed to connect to settings endpoint
```

Teams-Log:

```
Teams try 7 times to connect somewhere but this fails.
```

In [this tech community thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_win10-mso_o365b/microsoft-teams-crashes-when-opening-a-word/1acf1e03-710f-499a-9ce1-154470048bd8) are some more log files instances from when this error occurs.

EDIT:

Hi, today I found a workaround for the issue :)

1. Sign out and close any instances of Microsoft Teams running.
2. Navigate to the following path: %userprofile%\appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams
3. Create a json file called hooks.json
4. Use your favourite notepad editor, add the following line to the newly created file:

   `{"enableProcessIntegrityLevel": false}`
5. Save and close the file.
6. Now, re-open Microsoft Teams and sign in.

Source: [thread on answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_win10-mso_o365b/microsoft-teams-crashes-when-opening-a-word/1acf1e03-710f-499a-9ce1-154470048bd8)

We will now distribute the **hooks.json** file via a policy.

Comment: Hi @JuniorAdmin, did this approach with the hooks.json file work for you? If so, you should answer your own question and accept it instead of updating the question with your solution. Note that the thread you link to doesn't seem to be related to the hooks.json file.

Comment: Hello @AmosM.Carpenter, thanks for the hint, yes the solution worked for us but has not been needed for a long time since the MS Teams version was updated (to version 1.3?). Anyone who has installed MS Teams can check the functionality of the "hooks.json" file himself by setting any value in it and then checking whether this has been overwritten in the "settings.json". The links in my question have apparently been changed (by MahNas92?). I tried to find the original source, maybe it was this: "https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/website-tab-in-pc-app-not-showing/m-p/386478"

Answer (score 1):

the error no longer occurs since the MS teams application was updated ([can not remember but it should be one of the last versions of 1.2 or one of the first versions of 1.3](https://whatpulse.org/app/microsoft-teams)).

Here are the steps for the workaround again:

> - Sign out and close any instances of Microsoft Teams running.
> - Navigate to the following path: %userprofile%\appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams
> - Create a json file called **hooks.json**
> - Use your favourite notepad editor, add the following line to the newly created file: {"enableProcessIntegrityLevel": false}
> - Save and close the file.
> - Now, re-open Microsoft Teams and sign in.

In the current MS Teams version (1.3.00.30866 x86), the **settings.json** file contains the "enableProcessIntegrityLevel" value several times, sometimes it is "true" and sometimes "false". This led to a malfunction (webcams and microphones were sometimes no longer recognized), so that we had to delete the **hooks.json** files from the user profiles.

Until then, the solution with the hooks.json file had worked well. The solution can also be used for other purposes to define settings for the MS Teams application.

Sorry, I was not aware that questions that do not contain an answer are still considered unsolved.